# How to get active object in class and in jvm?

Tags: java, jvm

hello all my question is if we have 10 object of class and three of them passed to garbage collector. now we have seven active object. how can we get number of active object in class and in jvm.

Comment: How do you "pass them to the garbage collector"? Why do you need the number of active objects?

Comment: For what purpose? This is not something you ever need to know at runtime. You might need to know it during tuning, and there are tools for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `static` counter in the class and increment it in the constructor and decrement it in the finalizer, but I am not sure why you care.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assume something like that if you do `object= null` there is no guarantee that JVM will do garbage collection. `But since you don't have reference now you will not able to access it.`

In java you don't have to care about memory till your program exits with `OutOfMemoryException` but standard programming practices still apply :)

You can read more about [**The Reachability Lifecycle of Objects**](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/gcP.html)

You can use profiler to see active object count e.g [JProfiler](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/04/in-screencast-below-i-show-strategy-for.html)

As a solution you can use [Object Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) But it is a **anti-pattern**